# What's the electric field with a point charge not in the center of the sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, charge

That's a hollow conducting sphere link

My charge is at P (10uC). R = 0.15m. PS = 0.05m. DS = 0.35m. What's the electric field at point D? [image]

Comment: Is that the only charge in the sphere?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the point charge is the only charge in the sphere, the electric field will simply follow from Gauss's law:

$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\frac{q_p}{r_{PD}^2}\hat{r}_{PD}$$

Where $\hat{r}_{PD}$ is a unit vector pointing from P to D. Note that in this equation, $\epsilon$ is not the permittivity of free space, but rather the permittivity of the material in the sphere. So there will be a dielectric constant $k$ associated with the sphere, and the permittivity can be calculated as $k\epsilon_0$, where $\epsilon_0$ is $8.85 \times10^{-12}\frac{F}{m}$, as usual.