# Does the electric field inside a sphere change if point charge isn't in center?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-fields, charge

As i understood , if you have a point charge in the center of a hollow conducting sphere then the electric field inside it, is zero because the charge distribution is spherically symmetric.

But what's going on if the point charge isn't in the center of the sphere?

Will then be an Electric field inside the sphere? And will the outside electric field change?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57806/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field inside the sphere will not be zero if it is hollow and there is a point charge in the hollowed out part. The field will be zero in the conductor, because the field is always zero in a conductor in electrostatics.
What you might be refering to is that the field will be zero inside the hollow sphere if *it* is charged, because the charges will distribute symmetrically over the sphere.